# What is way to stream record from oracle db to kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to send occasionally record from oracle db to kafka topic. Is there a way to do so using procedure etc. without use of extra tools

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, detailed in [this blog](https://rmoff.net/2018/12/12/streaming-data-from-oracle-into-kafka/) and [this talk](https://rmoff.dev/oracle-and-kafka).

tl;dr:

- "Query-based" CDC, poll the database for changes, using [Kafka Connect JDBC Source connector](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-17&utm_term=rmoff-devx)
- "Log-based" CDC, use the redo log capture every change into Kafka, using GoldenGate / Qlik Attunity / etc etc etc

There's also a [REST API](https://www.confluent.io/blog/changing-face-etl/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-17&utm_term=rmoff-devx) if you want the lowest footprint, and then you just push records from a PL/SQL REST call over to Kafka. Probably fine for small infrequent volumes but it's going to be inflexible and brittle in the long run.